# how to remove black padded background after rotation of images

Tags: image, qt, applescript

I am new in Qt. I am working on rotation of images. In my case, rotation is working fine but after rotation black padded background appears. I want to remove or hide that black background.

I am working on MAC. so I am using "Imageevent" applescript. and my script is this: tell application "Image Events".

```
launch
 set this_image to open this_file
 rotate this_image to angle 270
 save this_image with icon
 close this_image
 end tell
```

besides this script i have also tried this Qt code for rotation of images:

```
void MyWidget::rotateLabel()
{
    QPixmap pixmap(*my_label->pixmap());
    QMatrix rm;
    rm.rotate(90);
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rm);
    my_label->setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

Comment: how do you rotate? post some code

Comment: This is not Qt problem, but applescript's, then.

Comment: hello Trompa, i have already tried the Qt code as well which i have edited in my question. Please go through that and tell me if u have any suggestion for me.\

Answer (score 2):

You can also pad images with a specified color...

```
set myFile to "/Users/JD/Desktop/test.png"
do shell script "sips -r 270 " & quoted form of myFile & " --padColor FFFFFF -i"
```

EDIT
You can save the script below as an application and drop files on it...

```
on open of theFiles
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        set filePath to quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
        do shell script "sips -r 270 " & filePath & " --padColor FFFFFF -i"
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: please tell me how to use it. i am not aware of usage of this script.i will really appreciate. thnks.

Comment: sorry adayzdone, its still not working for me. what i am doing is: i have written this script on text file then save it as .sh file run it on terminal. Am i on a right way or is there any problem ? pls tell me

Comment: Paste the second code into an AppleScript Editor window. Save as an application and then drag files to the resulting application icon.

Comment: Hey adayzdone,  if you don't mind one more i want to ask. i want to do this in my code. can i use this as a simple applescript as same as using in my question ?

Comment: Simply use lines 3 - 4 of the EDIT script. Replace the aFile variable with your this_file variable.

Comment: Hey adayzdone, While rotating again and again, the size of the image decreases. how can i stop this size decrement ? please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

sips seems to keep transparent backgrounds in at least PNG files:

```
sips -r 270 /tmp/a.png -o /tmp/b.png
```

You could also use ImageMagick:

```
convert -rotate 270 /tmp/a.png /tmp/b.png
```